# SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame IN FIRST ACCESS

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.app.teste.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I know about others post with the same issue. But i created this beacuse a have specify problem.

This error happens JUST IN FIRST ACCESS, when i press f5 to reload the page works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your HTTP_REFERER. Referer changes after reload.